# How to parse a condition stored in a variable as PySpark code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` and a string variable `cond` which contains a condition, lets say:

```
cond = """F.col('some-column').isin(['some-value'])"""
```

I need to apply/parse this condition that is stored as text on the dataframe `df`. How can I accomplish this?

I know if I change it a little bit, I can utilize SparkSQL. However, for a bunch of upcoming requirements, I would prefer this method. If it would be possible, that is.

Comment: Have you tried [eval with compile](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/)?

Comment: Use a eval means generally bad design. The proper way of doing that is DSK answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10025504/ghost)'s input, this turned out to be easier than I thought.

```
cond = """F.col('some-column').isin(['some-value'])"""

df = df.filter(eval(cond))
```

Comment: Yes..use of case statement with expr is also a great workaround for such use cases

Answer (score 0):

**IIUC , use filter on dataframe directly.**

```
a_list = [1, 2 3]
df = df.filter(F.col("col_name).isin([a_list]))
```

## Update the answer as per the understanding :)

```
# business logic in a case condition here
    logic = F.expr("""
            CASE WHEN column_name IN ('A', 'B', 'C') THEN '1'
                    WHEN column_name IN ('D', 'E', 'F') THEN '2'
                    ELSE column_name //or any_default_condition
              END""")

df = df.withColumn('new_column_name', logic)
```

Comment: This I know. Thing is, I am getting the condition as a string in a variable. I have to apply it to the dataframe. Like say, df.filter(magic_func(cond))

Comment: Updated the answer - Can you please check? Will appreciate if you could approve and upvote if you are looking for the same.. Thanks in advance !